# how to check the corrupted file while reading the parquet files?

Tags: parquet

I have some issue while reading parquets from hdfs, which are produced by my programs periodly. So it may produce some corrupted files if the program go down for some reason.

Now, what I want is to tell the corrupted files from the normal and move to backup dir. But I can't find a good way to do it.

There are two kinds of corrupted files I have met:

```
1.parquet is not a Parquet file (too small length: 4)
```

In this case, it's easy to tell because of its size

```
2.parquet is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [56, 52, 53, 51]
```

In thie case, I have no idea about telling it from the normal ones until reading it.

I have read this website:
https://datameer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006392072-Workbook-Fails-path-to-file-Is-Not-a-Parquet-File-Expected-Magic-Number-at-Tail

According to it, " that will be lower than the other file in place.>, but I can't find it yet.

Is there any good solution to deal with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to check the corrupted Files. I copy the functions readFooter() from ParquetFileReader.java to my project and use a iterator to get all the parquet files and apply readFooter() to them. Finally save these corrupted one in to an array and move it to another dirs.

Comment: can you give me code reference in doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

Both errors suggest that parquet file wasn't closed correctly during writing. Instead of checking for corruption when reading, I propose to modify writing logics as following:

1. Create new parquet file in temporary directory which is not seen by the readers
2. Write data you intended to write and close the file
3. Move the file to its correct location, where reader can find it

As such, reader will observe only correctly closed files. Broken files will remain in temporary directory.

Comment: I think yours is pretty good. But I have some questions for that. In my case, I use spark-structured-streaming to consume the data from kafka and save it by writeStream for every 10-minutes batch.  I have no idea how to do the second part which now do by spark-structured-streaming automically?